# Thinkpad W510 plus 2 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, displayport

Is it possible to connect a Lenovo W510 to two external DVI monitors and also use the built in screen, so that I am using a total of three monitors?

I don't have, nor do I want to purchase a dock, but a displayport adapter would be fine.

I just can't tell from my searches whether this is possible.  I have a NVIDI Quadro 1 Gb graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, but the will probably have some tearing problems. It's recommended that you have 1 monitor every one GB ram on your GPU. So you can do it, but when you have your moniters connected then you will have problems gaming and/or editing videos or images. So if you only use your laptop for stuff like excel, word, browsing etc then it's completely durable.

I hope you understood what i meant and i hope this helped you :D

Comment: The thing about ram is not true, flickering it's not caused by insufficient vram(video ram). I can use three monitors with no problems with my laptop wich has 128 mb of vram.

Comment: Flickering can be caused be vram, but I don't think it's going to be a problem.

Comment: I won't be video editing, but will be photo editing.  Can you explain what you mean by tearing?

Comment: Tearing is when the screen looks like it splits in two. It's hard to explain but you will know what i mean if you see it. It will be a problem with gaming, but not with video editing and photo editing. If you haven't got enough ram you will probably have a problem with rendering your pictures since that takes some ram to do, but the extra monitors won't take that much ram.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote because your answers the best (only) answer, but I think there will be issues specific to my model that should be considered.